# Where is jython jar located in webspehere application server home directory

Tags: websphere, cgi, jython

I want to write a CGI script for Jython for websphere application server task. The CGI script required shebang where in I need to give jython file path. I have WAS 8.5 and I couldnt fine the jython jar anywhere . where in Jython jar in WAS home directory.

Comment: I don't know what "WebSphere Application Server *task*" means; can you clarify?  To be clear, WebSphere Application Server itself does not natively support web applications written in Jython, and it does not support using the bundled Jython outside of wsadmin.  If you meant either of those, then you'll have to find another solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your cgi script would have to invoke jython scripts from wsadmin, as in the following example.

```
wsadmin -lang jython -f 'c:/temp/script/test1.py'
```

It would be best to call specific files from within a script, rather than just simply command line arguments. Keep in mind that each time you invoke wsadmin from within a script it will fire up a separate JVM, which can be very cpu intensive. So it is best to put most logic in external scripts and then call the few .py scripts separately from inside the cgi script.

wsadmin is located in

```
profiles/<profile_name>/bin
```

Rerefence:

[Jython Infocenter Info](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/cxml_jython.html?lang=en)